# Hosting an API and pushing Json data to S3 while converting it to Avro

Tags: json, amazon-s3, apache-nifi, avro

I want to host an API in Nifi using HandleHTTP processor. And i wanted to pass some dummy json data. I want to convert the JSON data to avro and then push it to S3 bucket.

I am getting the following error when the json data goes from HandleHTTPResponse to ConvertRecord (Which is converting json -> Avro), thus the data goes to this failure pipeline.

Can anyone help me out.

[image: Hosting an API and pushing Json data to S3 while converting it to Avro.]

Answer (score 0):

This means that in ConvertRecord you have a the Record Reader configured with "Schema Access Strategy" of "Schema Name", and you have "Schema Name" property set to the default of "${schema.name}", but your flow file does not have schema.name as an attribute.

You can change "Schema Name" to the hard-coded value of your schema name if you know it is going to be the same all the time, or you can send schema.name as a header on the request to HandleHttpRequest which would then put schema.name as an attribute.